# Удалить из map<***, vector<string>> пары с пустыми векторами

Tags: c++

Нужно удалить из словаря `map<***, vector<string>> Events` пары, в которых вектор строк пуст.
Я смог это сделать путем создания вектора, добавления в него нужных ключей и уже потом итерированием по этому вектору удалять значения:

```
vector<***> needDelete;

for(auto& item : events){
if(item.second.empty()) needDelete.push_back(item.first);
}

for(auto& item : needDelete){
Events.erase(item);
}
```

Но нет ли способа сделать эту операцию быстрее?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (auto it = Events.begin(); it != Events.end(); ) {
        if (it->second.empty())
            it = Events.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
}
```

Comment: Ага, уже сделал подобное у себя, но все равно спасибо :)